# Query for User by Id not returning that User

Tags: soql, unit-test, community

I am Creating a Test User whose Id is Assigned to a field on Account and I'm able to get to that Id just fine through my Community User however when I try to query Users with that Id it returns 0 rows even though it's an inserted User

**Test Class**

*The bmu User is the User I'm attempting to query for I assign it's Id to the field Brand_Manager__c on the dummy Account*

```
public class NewBrandCommunityHomepageControllerTest {
public class WrapperClass{
    User u;
    Account a;
    Contact c;
    User bmu;
}
static WrapperClass setUser(){
    String lastname2 = 'lastName';
    User bmu = new User(
        Alias = 'standt2', 
        IsActive = true,
        Email = lastname2 + '@test.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey ='UTF-8', 
        LastName = lastname2, 
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
        ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = :'Brand Manager'].Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles', 
        UserName = lastname2 + '@test.com'
    );

    insert bmu;      
    Account a = new Account(
        Name = 'Test Account',
        isActive__c = true,
        Account_Type__c = 'Premium L1',
        AccountLevel__c = 'Premium Plus',
        Brand_Manager__c = bmu.Id
    );
    H.Log(a.Brand_Manager__c);
    insert a;
    Contact c = new Contact(
        FirstName = 'Wave', 
        LastName = 'Test',
        AccountId = a.Id
    );
    insert c;
    String lastName = 'waveTest';
    User u = new User(
        Alias = 'standt', 
        IsActive = true,
        Email = lastName + '@test.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey ='UTF-8', 
        FirstName = 'Wave',
        LastName = lastName,
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
        ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Customer Community Plus User'].Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles', 
        UserName = lastName + '@test.com',
        ContactId = c.Id
    );
    insert u;
    WrapperClass wc = new WrapperClass();
    wc.u = u;
    wc.a = a;
    wc.c = c;
    wc.bmu = bmu;
    return wc;
}
static TestMethod void TestWaveContoller(){
    WrapperClass wc = setUser();
    Test.startTest();
    System.runAs(wc.u){
        NewBrandCommunityHomepageController cont = new NewBrandCommunityHomepageController();
        System.assertEquals(cont.BrandManager.Id, wc.bmu.Id);
    }
    Test.stopTest();
}}
```

**Controller**

```
public class NewBrandCommunityHomepageController {

public NewBrandCommunityHomepageController(){
    populateUsers();
}

public Account Account{get;set;}
public User BrandManager{get;set;}

public void populateUsers(){
    Account = 
        [SELECT Contact.Account.Id, Contact.Account.Name, Contact.Account.Brand_Manager__c, 
         Contact.Account.ContentAssociate__c, Contact.Account.Accounting__c, 
         Contact.Account.ComplianceAssociate__c, Contact.Account.Graphic_Designer__c,
         Contact.Account.IPA_Lead__c, Contact.Account.MarketingAssociate__c
         FROM User
         WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].Contact.Account;
    H.log(Account.Brand_Manager__c);
    BrandManager = 
        [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, SmallPhotoUrl, FullPhotoUrl, Email, Phone
         FROM User
         WHERE Id = :Account.Brand_Manager__c];}}
```

*I query for that User Id on Account (Brand_Manager__c) through the Contact related to a Community User then pass that to a query for that bmu User but it returns 0 rows but only in testing. And when I log Account it has the correct Id and everything its just unable to see that bmu User for whatever reason*

Comment: ``UserInfo.getUserId()`` will give you the userId for the user who is currently logged in. Are you using System.runAs() in your test class?

Comment: @abhi Yes I edited my question to reflect the Test Method I'm running

Comment: I think you're clipping out a lot of the code we need to see in order to answer the question. I appreciate the effort to only show what's relevant, but it looks like you're making your question impossible to answer.

Comment: What's the `WrapperClass wc = setUser();`? You need to show us a LOT more code for us to help you. Seems like you ought to be passing a parameter to that for it to be relevant. What user are you setting?

Comment: So I again edited my question to include all of my test and then the relevant part of my controller

Comment: Sometimes doing this works for me: after `insert bmu;` query for it again. so after that line, write `String bmuid = [select id from user where id =: bmu.id][0].id;` then use that bmuid for the `Brand_Manager__c`.

Comment: If that works, let me know and I'll submit it as an answer. I think it's some weird preinsert and postinsert id thing, or it's coming up as null when you're assign to brand_manager__c.

Comment: So I think I have it figured as to why it's failing, not how to fix it, but it's because I'm in a community it can't see that User when I query for it. even though when I actually view the page in question it with a community User it works just fine not entirely sure why there's a difference between the test and the actual page